# Closed form for the partial sum $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{\ln k}k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, closed-form

I'd like to find a closed form for this partial sum:
$$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{\ln k}k$$

Using the properties of the logarithms, I converted the above into
$$\ln\left(\prod_{k = 1}^n k^{1/k}\right),$$
but I don't know how to proceed.
Is this the right direction? If not, what can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have, by partial summation:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{H_k}{k} = H_n^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{H_k}{k+1} $$
hence it follows that:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{H_k}{k} = \frac{H_k^2+H_k^{(2)}}{2} \tag{1}$$
and since:
$$ H_n = \log n +\gamma +\frac{1}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\tag{2} $$
it follows that:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log k}{k} = O(1)+ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{H_k-\gamma}{k}=O(1)+\frac{1}{2}H_k^2-\gamma H_k=\frac{1}{2}\log^2 n+O(1).\tag{3}$$

Comment: You could have easily used the integral test's bounds to show this and get something better than just $\mathcal O(1)$.

Comment: @SimpleArt: I wrote this answer a while ago, I cannot say at first glance if your claim is right or not (I would be tempted to say that approximations derived from summation by parts or Abel's integral formula are pretty the same thing), but I will spend some time tomorrow in digging into that. Thanks for the suggestion, always appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's asymptotically $O(\log^2 n)$, you can get it using Euler-Maclaurin formula. I don't think closed-form expression exists.

Comment: Thanks! Never heard of it, how would I go about finding the asymptotics?

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked. I looked the Euler-Maclaurin formula up and didn't understand how to apply it.

Comment: Just compare it to the corresponding integral, and the next term is $o(\log^2 n)$.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that a closed form exists on the basis of elementary functions.

There is a closed form which involves the gives the Stieltjes constant as well as the generalized Stieltjes constant $$\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{\ln k}k=\gamma _1-\gamma _1(n+1)$$ what I am not sure you will enjoy.

Comment: That's a bit misleading imho

Comment: @Alex. May I confess I totally agree ?

Comment: Ought to have a little star on it or something