# If $ f(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (n / i) \log(n / i) $ and $ g(n) = n ~ {\log^{2}}(n) $, then is $ O(f) = O(g) $?

Tags: limits, summation, computational-complexity

I was trying to prove that if 
$$f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n}{i} \log\frac{n}{i} $$
$$g(n) = n \log^2n$$
then $O(f(n)) = O(g(n))$

I am not sure that it is the case, but based on my simulation $$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \approx 0.536...$$ and slightly decreasing with increase of $n$.

I tried to tackle the problem by using induction. I started with some basic case and tried to prove that if this one is correct, the next one will be correct as well (which left me nowhere). I tried the same approach but instead of proving that $n+1$ will be correct I tried to prove that $2n$ will be correct (I want to show that [asymptotic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) holds, so I thought that this is ok). The second approach also failed.

What is the right approach to this problem (or may be $O(f(n))$ is not $O(g(n))$). If my guess is correct it would be also nice to know if there is a value for the limit.

Comment: Try splitting the sum into two parts by expanding the log. Then use the [well known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Rate_of_divergence) asymptotic $(\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i) - \log(n) \to \gamma$. The second term can be bounded to give the result. A rough calculation like this gives me $f(n) = \frac{n\log^2(n)}{2} + \gamma n\log(n) + n\log(n)A_n - nB_n$ where $A_n = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}-\log(n)-\gamma$ and $B_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\log(i)}{i}-\frac{1}{2}\log^2(n)$ satify $\lim_{n\to \infty} A_n = 0$ and $B_n$ is bounded(?). It seems $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \to 1/2$.

Comment: btw the second term ($B_n$) is [discussed here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166230/closed-form-for-the-partial-sum-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-ln-kk/1166237#1166237) and it is bounded (in fact it converges)

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to write "$O(f) = O(g)$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** One may recall that, by the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), as $n \to \infty$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i &=\ln n+\gamma+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac 1n\right)\\
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {\ln i}i &=\frac 12\ln^2 n+\gamma_1+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac {\ln n}n\right)
\end{align}
$$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html) and $\gamma_1$ is the [Stieltjes constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesConstants.html).

Then we may write, as $n \to \infty$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(n) &=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {n}i \ln\frac {n}i\\\\
&=n \ln n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i -n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {\ln i}i\\\\
&=n \ln n \left(\ln n+\gamma+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac 1n\right) \right) -n \left(\frac 12\ln^2 n+\gamma_1+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac {\ln n}n\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac n2\ln^2 n+\gamma \:n \ln n-\gamma_1\:n+\mathcal{O}\left( \ln n \right)
\end{align}
$$ In particular, you have $f(n)=\mathcal{O}(n\ln^2 n)$ and since $g(n)=n\ln^2 n$, you obtain
$$
\mathcal{O}\left(f(n)\right) = \mathcal{O}\left(g(n)\right),
$$ as announced.

Comment: Can you please explain this part: $f(n) =\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {n}i \ln\frac {n}i
=n \ln n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i -n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {\ln i}i$ I am not sure I understand it.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Yes, you have $$ \frac {n}i \ln\frac {n}i=\frac {n}i (\ln n -\ln i)=n \ln n \frac 1i-n \frac { \ln i}i$$ then you sum over $i$. Thanks.

Comment: @SalvadorDali You are welcome!